# Changing the scene in spritekit swift issue

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to change scene's once the player hits a green box, I am having a problem changing the scenes to the next level.  In my project I have Level2Scene.swift and Level2Scene.sks I use the Level2Scene.sks to design the level and I use the Level2Scene.swift to control what happens in the scene.  Here is my code that I have for when the player hits the green box.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var bodyA = contact.bodyA
    var bodyB = contact.bodyB

    var transition: SKTransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
    let scene: SKScene = Level2Scene(fileNamed: scene!.size)

    if bodyA.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 2 || bodyA.categoryBitMask == 2 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 1{

        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

The problem is in the  let scene: SKScene = Level2Scene(fileNamed: scene!.size)
The error says "Variable used within its own initial value"

Answer (score 1):

this looks weird to me..

```
let scene: SKScene = Level2Scene(fileNamed: scene!.size)
```

try

```
let scene: SKScene = Level2Scene(size: self.size)
```

Comment: I tried that and it the app crashes when I try to hit the green box.  It says "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Comment: you need to decide if youre trying to create your scene from a file.. or dimensions.  you cant mix the two.  i dont know what youre trying to do from  looking at your code.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is.

```
let scene = Level2Scene(size: scene!.size)
```

you are using the `scene` variable in the parameters for creating the `Level2Scene`
You'll probably need to grab the size from something other than the scene that you have not yet created.